# Displaying a users first name on Welcome page through a servlet JDBC

Tags: java, servlets, jdbc, authentication

I have the working code here to pull all info that I need from my users and user info table located in an oracle database :

```
try
        {
            conn = DB_Admin.getConnection();
            pstmnt = conn.prepareStatement("SELECT u.username, u.password, ui.user_id, " +
                                            "ui.f_name, ui.l_name, ui.email, ui.dob FROM users u " +
                                            "JOIN user_info ui ON ui.user_id = u.user_id " +
                                            "WHERE u.username = ? AND u.password = ?");
            pstmnt.setString(1, username);
            pstmnt.setString(2, password);
            rs = pstmnt.executeQuery();
            boolean exists = rs.next();

                    ...
```

And I have a servlet which is I am trying to make display the users first name after he/she logs in:

```
String username = request.getParameter("username").toString();
        String password = request.getParameter("password").toString();

        User user1 = new User(username, password);
        User user2 = new User(username,password, user1.getF_name(), user1.getL_name(), user1.getEmail(), user1.getDob());

        //HttpSession session = request.getSession();
        //session.setAttribute("f_name", user1.getF_name());

        boolean valid = ud.login(username, password);
        try{
            if(!valid)
            {
            //  request.setAttribute("var", companies);
                response.sendRedirect("login.html");
                logger.warn("Login Servlet : " + username + " has failed at logging in");
            }
            else
            {
                //response.sendRedirect("index.jsp");
                request.setAttribute("f_name",user2.getF_name());
                RequestDispatcher rd = request.getRequestDispatcher("index.jsp");
                rd.forward(request, response);
                logger.info("Login Servlet : " + username + " has logged in");
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex) { out.println(ex.getMessage()); }
```

In my User class I have getters and setters for all fields: "f_name, email, etc."

I know this code is written incorrectly, and I keep getting a "null" value on my welcome page.

Comment: Can you show where you get the `null` value in your page? By the way, after authenticating and validating the user, its basic data (username, preferences, etc.) should be saved in session instead of being saved as request attributes.

Answer (score 0):

First you should be able to get data you need from the executed query this way

```
String username = null;
while(rs.next){
username = rs.getString(1);
}
```

rs.getString method can be called either by index of columns in the order you have made in the executing query OR you can simple place the number by the name of the column of the original database

```
for example:

username = rs.getString("username");
```

Here you have the username returned in the executed query and you can easily print it in the jsp